# How to repair this false statement about idoneal numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-forms, primality-test

In the german wikipedia , I found [this](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerus_idoneus) site about idoneal numbers.

The mentioned statement is false :

- $D=1848$ is an idoneal number and $m=1849$ is an odd number.
- $x^2+1848y^2=1849$ has only one solution in positive integers, namely $x=y=1$.
- Since $(1,1848)=1$, $m$ should be prime, however it is a square of a prime ($43^2$).

> Does the statement become valid if we rule out that $m$ is a perfect square, or do we still need other conditions ?

I also looked in the english wikipedia , but there is no criterion given for a prime, only a criterion for a prime power or twice a prime power. Of course, this can easily be verified , but there should be a way to use idoneal numbers for a direct primality test.

Comment: It is interesting that the [German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerus_idoneus) says that there is at most one more while the [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idoneal_number) says that there are at most two more.  The [Kani reference](http://www.labmath.uqam.ca/~annales/volumes/35-2/PDF/197-227.pdf) says *"Frei claims that Weinberger’s result implies that there is at most one idoneal number $n > 1848$, and this assertion is frequently repeated in the literature; ... this cannot be true unless we could show that there are no even idoneal numbers for $n > 1848$."*

Comment: @Henry In fact, I noticed this discrepancy as well. Apparently TWO more idoneal numbers are possible. It seems that this theory has not been established very rigorously. Is it because such primality tests have no practical value ? But this is barely an excuse for such sloppiness.

Comment: Moreover, some cources claim that the list is complete assuming the generalized riemann hypothesis and other sources only claim that under this hypothesis there is at most one more idoneal number. Quite confusing !